# htaccess two commands in the same file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Hi i have my htaccess with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

if i erase the first 4 lines, the other piece of code (which redirects de 404 page when there's a page not found) does not work anymore.

Any ideas? 
I also want that when it redirects to 404.htm, it does not show on the url box, this url

**http://www.mypage.com/404.htm**

i want to show this

**http://www.mypage.com/fail/search-by-the-user**

for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

**NOTE**: if you are working at localhost then please mention proper RewriteBase

Comment: first problem solved, do you know a solution for the second one?

Comment: @Nick, not getting your second problem, please mention it clearly

Comment: if you go to:

google.com/dhfjsdfsdjfsd the error loads on that page, it does not redirect to a page called "404" or "not-found".

but in my page, it redirects to "404.htm" and i don't want that to be seen

Comment: @Nick, this working is working with ErrorDocument that mention at last in .htaccess. and it doesn't redirect, just output 404 document

Comment: but if i put www.mypage.com/404 instead of 404 (because css does not load if i put just 404) it redirects :(

Comment: @NIck, for css and image use full path in 404 document, it will work

Comment: but if i use full path it redirects to www.mypage.com/404.htm and i don't want that to be shown, i just want the users can see the unexistent url that they typed

Comment: @Nick, Don't use full path into .htaccess, use full path of CSS file into your 404.htm